# Looping items retrieves results more than once

Tags: jquery, loops, iteration

I have a click event to display the text of the chosen color but looping through the array of colors, i get all the items inside it instead of just getting the corresponding one. So far i'm able to get the color text but it is repeated five times.

For example click Black square shows Black, Black, Black, Black, Black. I need to show it just once.

Here is the HTML:

```
<fieldset class="radio col-xs-12 noPadding">
<label data-variantcolor="#000000" data-colorText="Black" class="radio" 
for="VARGRP1_0" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><input type="radio" 
value="VO26" name="VARGRP1" id="VARGRP1_0">                        <span 
style="display: none;">Black</span>
</label>
<label data-variantcolor="#008000   " data-colorText="Green" class="radio 
active" for="VARGRP1_1" style="background-color: rgb(0, 128, 0);"><input 
type="radio" value="VO27" name="VARGRP1" id="VARGRP1_1">                        
<span style="display: none;">Green</span>
</label>
<label data-variantcolor="#D60A0A" data-colorText="Red" class="radio" 
for="VARGRP1_2" style="background-color: rgb(214, 10, 10);"><input 
type="radio" value="VO4" name="VARGRP1" id="VARGRP1_2">                        
<span style="display: none;">Red</span>
</label>
<label data-variantcolor="#FFFF00   " data-colorText="Yellow" class="radio" 
for="VARGRP1_3" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);"><input 
type="radio" value="VO31" name="VARGRP1" id="VARGRP1_3">                        
<span style="display: none;">Yellow</span>
</label>
<label data-variantcolor="#FFFFFF" data-colorText="White" class="radio" 
for="VARGRP1_4" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><input 
type="radio" value="VO30" name="VARGRP1" id="VARGRP1_4">                        
<span style="display: none;">White</span>
</label>
</fieldset>
```

```
 var $colors = $("#VARGRP1 > fieldset > label"); //the colored buttons
 var $colorText = $(".colorVariantText"); //the span element to display the color text i.e: Red           

        for(var i = 0; i < $colors.length; i++)
        {
            $colors.eq(i).css("background-color", $colors.eq(i).attr("data-variantcolor"));
            $colors.find("span").css("display", "none");

            (function (i) {
                $colors.click( function () {
                        $colorText.html($(this).eq(i).attr("data-colorText")); 
                });
            })(i);

        }
```

Comment: Do you mind posting your HTML?

Comment: Sorry, just added it

Comment: Another issue is: `colortext` vs `colorText`!

Comment: Would you mind checking my answer?

Comment: I copied the HTML from dev tools that is why colortext comes with lowercase. Anyway it is not working yet. The problem might be because i'm generating that span element inside a foreach loop using Razor therefore calling the color text the same times it exists. Is there a way to avoid repeating the same item more than once?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman your answer does work but not in the case where results are coming from a loop. Anyway thanks for the help in optimizing my code

Comment: By the way, i shouldn't have had the .colorText element coming from within a loop. I just took it outside and have it fill the content with the color text value and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use `$.each()`. Assuming, you have the following HTML, I have used the right functions here and you don't even need a closure in this case.

```
var $colors = $("#VARGRP1 > fieldset > label"); //the colored buttons
var $colorText = $(".colorVariantText"); //the span element to display the color text i.e: Red           

$colors.each(function () {
  $(this).css("background-color", $(this).data("variantcolor"));
  $colors.find("span").css("display", "none");
});
$colors.click( function () {
  $colorText.html($(this).attr("data-colorText")); 
});
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
var $colors = $("#VARGRP1 > fieldset > label"); //the colored buttons
var $colorText = $(".colorVariantText"); //the span element to display the color text i.e: Red           

$colors.each(function () {
  $(this).css("background-color", $(this).data("variantcolor"));
  $colors.find("span").css("display", "none");
});
$colors.click( function () {
  $colorText.html($(this).attr("data-colorText")); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div id="VARGRP1">
  <fieldset>
    <label data-variantcolor="red" data-colorText="red">
      Click Me!
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label data-variantcolor="green" data-colorText="green">
      Click Me!
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label data-variantcolor="black" data-colorText="black">
      Click Me!
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label data-variantcolor="blue" data-colorText="blue">
      Click Me!
      <span></span>
    </label>
    <label data-variantcolor="orange" data-colorText="orange">
      Click Me!
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="colorVariantText"></div>
```